# Use custom delimiter for inline minted environment

Tags: listings, minted, code

Using the `listings` package, we can do the following to create a `|` (pipe)-delimited inline code environment:

```tex
\lstMakeShortInline|
```

I am interested in using the `minted` package instead, however it doesn't seem to support a similar shortcut. How can I make the pipe character delimit an inline code snippet, using `\mintinline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following provides a macro `\makemintedshortinline` that takes two parameters. The language which should be used and the character you want to be the shorthand.

It is not necessary to escape the character (use `\|` instead of `|`) for every character, but since it is necessary for some (for example `%` couldn't be input directly and you have to use `\%` instead), it doesn't hurt to use it.

It isn't checked whether the character already has a definition when it is turned active, so you can also change the language used this way, e.g., you could use `\makemintedshortinline{python}\|` after you used it to format LaTeX code to format Python code later in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand\makemintedshortinline[2]
  {%
    \catcode`#2=13
    \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#2
    \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \protected\def~{\mintinline{#1}~}%
    }%
  }

\makemintedshortinline{latex}\|

\begin{document}

|\verb+input+|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, worked as a drop-in replacement for `\lstMakeShortInline`. Thanks!